# How to make the text contents and variables to print in next line in php

Tags: php

I want to print the text contents and variable in next line, in my code the datat's are retreived using sql query and it is displayed using echo stetement. My codes are as follows

```
echo '<input type="hidden" id="imgdesc"  value="Disease_name:'.$result->Disease_name.',Patient_age:'.$result->Patient_age.',Patient_sex:'.$result->Patient_sex.',Disease_duration:'.$result->Disease_duration.',Family_history:'.$result->Family_history.',Affected_bodyPart:'.$result->Affected_bodyPart.',Medical_historys:'.$result->Medical_history.'" /></td>';
```

For the Above query i am getting the output as follows

Disease_name:ACPToParthenium,Patient_age:70,Patient_sex:Male,Disease_duration:6 months,Family_history:No similar cases,Affected_bodyPart:Leg,Medical_historys:Patient has no other diseases

But i want the output in following format

1. Disease_name: ACPToParthenium
2. Patient_age: 70
3. Patient_sex: Male
4. Disease_duration: 6 months
5. Family_history: No similar cases
6. Affected_bodyPart: Leg,Medical_historys
7. Medical_historys: Patient has no other diseases

Is there any way that i can make it using 'br' tag or any other method ?

Comment: Can you give the php code?

Comment: $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Disease_name, path, Disease_ID, Patient_age, Patient_sex, Disease_duration, Family_history, Affected_bodyPart, Medical_history FROM disease_info WHERE id >= $current_picture and DiseaseName_ID = $dropdown_val LIMIT 1")->fetch_object();

Comment: Please include that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you need to use a textarea, not a text input field.

```
<textarea name="your_input_field" cols="30" rows="7"></textarea>
```

The 'cols' field is the width of your textarea and the 'rows' are the number of lines in your textarea (like rows of a table).

Also, I'm not sure why you are trying to do this as your code above is a hidden field anyway?

From your comments below, I think this may match your needs (I've left the values as blank, but obviously these need to have the values you want to pass through in them):

```
<input type="hidden" name="disease_name" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="patient_age" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="patient_sex" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="disease_duration" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="family_history" value="">
```

Then on the second page, you could easily display these in the format you want using either a table of textarea, by doing this (I'm not sure whether your using GET or POST, so I've just used GET):

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td><?=$_GET['disease_name']?></td>
      <td><?=$_GET['patient_age']?></td>
      <td><?=$_GET['patient_sex']?></td>
      <td><?=$_GET['disease_duration']?></td>
      <td><?=$_GET['family_history']?></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i am using text area to display these contents, but its coming in a single line

Comment: The code you have posted isn't a text area. It's an input field with text in it - there's a difference. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Comment: I am passing these vaules to other page that is why i have used id=imgdesc

Comment: You can have use that id with the textarea instead and the information will still be passed to the next page. Have you tried replacing the <input type="hidden"> part with a textarea instead?

Comment: Am getting all the values, my problem is it should come in different lines within the textarea

Comment: So is this a form posting to the next page? You haven't worded your original question very well if this is the case. You won't be able to receive the text in that format when passing it to the next page, as it is just passed through as text - it doesn't matter what format it is displayed in on the first page. A very simple solution to this problem (if you don't want to process the output on the second page) is to store each numbered field in a seperate hidden input field, with a unique ID so you know what is stored in them.

Comment: I am confused as to what you are doing. Is the input field in your original question on the first or second page?

Comment: It is in second page, and i got your point i will try it .And thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

You can display the values in different  or you may display display them in separate

tags.

```
<td><?php echo "Disease_name:".$result->Disease_name; ?></td>
<td><?php echo "Patient_age:".$result->Patient_age; ?></td>
```

and so on...

Comment: Hi nutty programmer, i tried this method but the second values is not displaying, I am passing these values to other page and using jquery i am displaying it in text area

Comment: You can try use multiple hidden field to get values separately and add styling using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to echo in lines:

```
  echo '<textarea name="someting" cols="30" rows="7">';
    echo 'Disease_name: ' . $result->Disease_name . '<br/>';
    echo 'Patient_age: ' . $result->Patient_age . '<br/>';
    echo 'Patient_sex: ' . $result->Patient_sex . '<br/>';
    echo 'Disease_duration' . $result->Disease_duration . '<br/>';
    echo 'Family_history: ' . $result->Family_history . '<br/>';
    echo 'Affected_bodyPart: ' . $result->Affected_bodyPart . '<br/>';
    echo 'Medical_historys: ' . $result->Medical_historys;
   echo '</textarea>';
```